# File transfer through SMB protocol android error

Tags: android, jcifs

I want to transfer file from my app to wireless samba device.I written follwing code but not work.Device having ip=192.168.1.2:8181 with Username=Admin and Password=[empty].While the device show the complete files when i try to access it from my pc browser.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

import jcifs.smb.NtlmPasswordAuthentication;
import jcifs.smb.SmbException;
import jcifs.smb.SmbFile;
import jcifs.smb.SmbFileInputStream;
import jcifs.smb.SmbFileOutputStream;


public class Samba extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_samba);



        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
        /*
         * Do something
         */

                try {
                    String yourPeerPassword = "";
                    String yourPeerName = "Admin";
                    String yourPeerIP = "192.168.1.2:8181";

                    String smfilepath = "smb://" + yourPeerIP + "//dummy.txt.txt";

                    NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication(
                            null, yourPeerName, yourPeerPassword);

                    Log.e("Connected", "Yes");
                    SmbFile smbFile = new SmbFile(smfilepath, auth);
                    /** Printing Information about SMB file which belong to your Peer **/
                    String nameoffile = smbFile.getName();
                    String pathoffile = smbFile.getPath();
                    Log.e(nameoffile, pathoffile);
                    Log.e("Path", "Yes");

                    SmbFileOutputStream smbfos = new SmbFileOutputStream(smbFile);
                    smbfos.write("testing....and writing to a file".getBytes());
                    smbfos.close();
/*
                    SmbFile Dest=new SmbFile(smfilepath,auth);

                    Log.e("file", "dest");
                    downloadFileFromPeerToSdcard(Dest);
                    Log.e("after fun", "Yes");*/
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.e("MalformURL", e.getMessage());
                } catch (SmbException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.e("SMBException", e.getMessage());
                }catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.e("Not Connected", e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });

        t.start();



    }
}
```

Log Error:

```
10-05 09:47:41.220    6332-7651/loginscreen.example.com.girviapp E/Connected﹕ Yes
10-05 09:47:41.220    6332-7651/loginscreen.example.com.girviapp E/dummy.txt.txt﹕ smb://192.168.1.2:8181//dummy.txt.txt
10-05 09:47:41.220    6332-7651/loginscreen.example.com.girviapp E/Path﹕ Yes
10-05 09:47:49.897    6332-7490/loginscreen.example.com.girviapp W/System.err﹕ jcifs.smb.SmbException: Failed to connect: 0.0.0.0<00>/192.168.1.2
10-05 09:47:49.897    6332-7545/loginscreen.example.com.girviapp W/art﹕ Long monitor contention event with owner method=void jcifs.smb.SmbTree.treeConnect(jcifs.smb.ServerMessageBlock, jcifs.smb.ServerMessageBlock) from SmbTree.java:136 waiters=0 for 22.506s
10-05 09:47:49.897    6332-7490/loginscreen.example.com.girviapp W/System.err﹕ jcifs.util.transport.TransportException: Connection timeout
10-05 09:47:49.897    6332-7490/loginscreen.example.com.girviapp W/System.err﹕ at jcifs.util.transport.Transport.connect(Transport.java:174)
10-05 09:47:49.897    6332-7490/loginscreen.example.com.girviapp W/System.err﹕ at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.connect(SmbTransport.java:307)
10-05 09:47:49.897    6332-7490/loginscreen.example.com.girviapp W/System.err﹕ at jcifs.smb.SmbTree.treeConnect(SmbTree.java:156)
10-05 09:47:49.898    6332-7490/loginscreen.example.com.girviapp W/System.err﹕ at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.doConnect(SmbFile.java:911)
10-05 09:47:49.898    6332-7490/loginscreen.example.com.girviapp W/System.err﹕ at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.connect(SmbFile.java:957)
10-05 09:47:49.898    6332-7490/loginscreen.example.com.girviapp W/System.err﹕ at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.connect0(SmbFile.java:880)
10-05 09:47:49.898    6332-7490/loginscreen.example.com.girviapp W/System.err﹕ at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.open0(SmbFile.java:975)
10-05 09:47:49.898    6332-7490/loginscreen.example.com.girviapp W/System.err﹕ at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.open(SmbFile.java:1009)
```

Comment: What is the exact symptom you face instead of "not work"?

Comment: file content not updated on device when i am checking on device

Answer (score 0):

You should install a log collector app to find out whether you generated any error.

[This](http://www.androlib.com/android.application.com-xtralogic-android-logcollector-zpn.aspx) might be helpful.

After that, you can find the probable cause in the error log.
If you could not write to the file, at least an IOException should have been thrown.

Also, it can be helpful double checking that you have no shared folder name (that is, you really want to write to the unnamed root folder on your SMB device), and if so, removal of one of the two slashes after the port from the SMB url (between which the share name should be put) might be helpful.

Comment: Does anybody have same issue before